# Am unable to use the foreach loop in the template in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

What I want to do is use the

> erb select and the foreach loop

to create a select menu(drop down menu) and these are what have done
Step 1: create the State model and migrate the created ruby file with

> rails db:migrate

Step2: Include @state in the StaticController like

```
def index
  @states = State.new
end
```

And in the view which is the last step did this

```
<%= f.label :state %>
 <% @states.each do |state| %>
 <%= f.select :state, (value:state.states) %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the error I got

> undefined method `each' for #State id: nil, states: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil

Meanwhile in the PGAdmin(Postgre Admin), have inserted some names and I can view them in PGAdmin

Comment: `@states = State.new` says that `@states` is a single `State`, perhaps you meant `@states = State.all`.

Comment: Oh! What a silly mistake..I never see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did two mistakes:

1. I don't think you want to initialize a new object of `State`, probably you want to get all states, in this case, you should use `State.all`;
2. The way you did to set the options for the select isn't correct, take a look at the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) (one way to pass the options for the `select` helper is `f.select(:state_id, @states.collect { |state| [ state.name, state.id ] })`).

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the link and for putting me through